# How to stop TeamCity building the entire history after migrating the Git repository?

Tags: git, teamcity

After migrating a Git repository (including all history) to the cloud and pointing TeamCity to the new location, TeamCity is rebuilding every check-in since the repository was originally created...

So The queue is full, and all agents are engaged in this operation, and I'm not shure how long it is going to take if I just leave it.

So two questions:

1. Why is TeamCity doing this?
2. How can I prevent it? (other than canceling everything in the build queue when this happens)

Comment: As to "Why is TeamCity doing this?" - What is stated in "triggered by" of the builds? What are the settings of the related trigger?

Comment: Yes, there is a VCS trigger on the build, so I guess the ID of each change-set changes during migration and TeamCity thinks they are all new? Sounds like plausible explanation. The check-in dates do seem to be preserved after the migration. It is not a huge problem, only a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop it - just go to the build config *Triggers* -> *VCS Trigger* and uncheck the **Trigger a build on each check-in** option.